# GitBash on the MAC

Tags: git, terminal, git-bash

I am trying to follow [Set up SSH for Gi](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git).  it goes on about opening GitBash but is this something else to terminal? As i follow this within the mac terminal and i get most of it but the ending as it does not work so i think its GitBash i need and not terminal so where can i find this on the mac?

I get as far as step 5 then section 6 where when i reopen gitbash i should get the passphrase question etc but nothing and when i list identities ssh-add -l i get nothing.

Comment: "GitBash" seems to be an error in the document (or at least poorly written), it could mean the msysgit Bash for Windows machines, or it could simply mean whichever Bash terminal has Git on whatever operating system you're using.

Comment: do you know i thought so its just that i am havign to reset my keys on both local and work machines to the remote bitbucket account every time i start the machines and i thought it might be that i was missing this, but if its simply my terminal then... thansk

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think you may find it helpful.

Comment: You're probably looking at the "Set up SSH for Windows", Reload that page and expand "Set up SSH for Mac OS/Linux" instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

I was finally able to bring up the webpage at [Set up SSH for Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git). At the top of the page, you'll see a ***big green notice box*** with this message (emphasis mine):

> ***Linux or Mac User***?
>
> This page shows you how to set up and use a single default SSH identity on Windows for a Git repository using GitBash. In the next page, you set up SSH for a Mercurial repository on Windows with TortoiseHg. ***If you are working on Mac OSX or Linux, a single set of instructions shows you [how to setup and identity for either Git or Mercurial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678) in these environments***.

Since you're using a Mac, you should see if the instructions at the given help link solve your problems. To be clear, here is the link again:

- **[Set up SSH for Git and Mercurial on Mac OSX/Linux](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678)**.

If it helps, here is a screenshot of the original notice box too:

[image]

---

## Old answer (still has useful info for running ssh-agent manually though)

I can't read your link right now because my browser won't open the page, but from your description, it sounds like you're trying to get `ssh-agent` to start automatically whenever you open up a terminal. Do you have `ssh-agent` already installed and in your path?

You don't need to configure `ssh-agent` to run automatically, you can just invoke it manually. Try

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

Then run `ssh-add` to enter your passphrase for your private key. Be sure to shutoff `ssh-agent` when you're done using `ssh-agent -k`.

Answer (score -3):

Atlassian has an AMAZING resource for GIT. If you are new to git, I would highly recommend using their GIT GUI,
[SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview)

SourceTree should automatically setup GIT on your machine, and manage your repo right from the application.

Then you can just use the following command to see if you have git installed:

```
$ which git
```

If it doesn't come back empty, you have it installed. But at this point, you can do everything in SourceTree. No need to do it via command line.

Comment: I actually highly recommend that people learn to use Git from the command line, not a GUI like SourceTree, because GUIs have a big tendency to abstract away too much knowledge about how Git actually works. It's good to be proficient with Git from the command line, instead of a GUI. I highly recommend that people read the [***FREE*** online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book) to learn how to use Git proficiently and expertly from the command line. In particular, chapters 1-3 and 6-6.5 are important for typical users.

Comment: Well thanks to both of you but i agree with @Cupcake as i have tried source tree and found it what if ok but Git has taught me to use the terminal more and be less afraid and more open to the terminal. With regards to my question though is what is gitbash i have set up identities several times but once the machine is closed then i restart it seems to keep telling me no permissions or identities so looking into ways gitbash is mentioned open in gitbash etc but what is it all i use is the terminal?

Comment: You are right, diving into CLI is a great way to learn. I would like to note, that my experience was opposite (Though, neither is wrong). I learned git using SourceTree, and since then, I can work seamlessly between CLI and GUI. I also use HUB (https://github.com/github/hub) CLI for easier interaction with Github. Good luck to you, and I hope you find what you are looking for, going either direction.